# How to create a dataframe with combinations of values within a column

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools, fraud-prevention

Alright guys, this one's tough.

The subject of this ask is based on fraud data, rules and payments - i think it's easier to picture what i'm trying to do with a little background.

I have a dataframe that consists of accountids, amounts, dates, fraud etc. and one column called rule. There can be many unique rules that fired per accountid.

```
accountid    amount    date      rule   fraud
123          5         20191101  rule_1  fraud
123          10        20191102  rule_2  fraud
456          50        20191101  rule_1  nonfraud
456          50        20191101  rule_2  nonfraud
456          50        20191101  rule_3  nonfraud
456          50        20191101  rule_4  nonfraud
```

My goal is to create a function that iterates through each combination of 2 rules (maybe 3 later on), and have a couple other columns that count accountids, count number of fraud and nonfraud accountids, fraudrate etc. result looks like this:

```
rule_combo       count_acct     count_fraud   count_nonfraud    fraudrate
rule_1,rule_2    5              3             2                 .6
rule_2,rule_3    20             10            10                .5
rule_2,rule_4    50             10            40                .1
rule_1,rule_3    10             3             7                 .3
```

I have a function that looks like this that will do what I want but it uses columns (headers):

```
def combo_cols(df,agg,cols,n,minrate=0)
    combos = list(itertools.combinations(cols,3))
    num_cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
    res = []
    for combo in combos:
        fr = fraudrate(df,agg,combo) #using another function
        accounts = df.groupby(combo).apply(lambda df:list(df.accountid.unique()))
        accounts.name = 'accounts'
        accounts = accounts.to_frame()
        fr = accounts.join(fr)
        fr = fr.reset_index()
        fr['naccts'] = fr.apply(lamda df: len(set(df.accounts)),axis=1)
        fr.columns = num_cols + ['accounts','naccts','fraud','nonfraud','fraudrate','fpr']
        fr = fr.assign(groupcols = ', '.join(combo))
        fr = fr.loc[fr.fraudrate.gt(minrate)]
        res.append(fr)
    return pd.concat(res).sort_values(by='fraudrate',ascending=False)
```

I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to write a function that would do this for rules. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I am answering to your question, so please give me feedback and I will update if needed.

My first bet would be to OneHotEncode those features you have. Here is an example:

`df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['rule', 'fraud'])`

Which result in this:

```
accountid amount rule_rule_1 rule_rule_2 rule_rule_3 rule_rule_4 fraud_fraud fraud_nonfraud
0   123     5        1           0           0           0           1           0
1   123     10       0           1           0           0           1           0
2   456     50       1           0           0           0           0           1
3   456     50       0           1           0           0           0           1
4   456     50       0           0           1           0           0           1
5   456     50       0           0           0           1           0           1
```

Then you could use itertools to make something like this:

```
import itertools
for elt in itertools.combinations(list(df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('rule')]), 2):
    tmp = df.groupby(list(elt))
    # Apply your aggregation functions here
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You understood the question perfectly. I had not heard of that get_dummies() method - that is awesome. I used that and passed in a list of all of the rule columns that get_dummies created and basically ran the same script I had previously, which is very similar to your for loop. Thanks so much for your help man!